# PL/SQL 'select .. where .. in' using local table collection

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, types

I'm using Oracle 11 and this code doesn't seem working:

```
procedure test()
as
    type StrTable is table of number;

    --local variable
    testTable StrTable;

begin
    testTable := StrTable();

    --add values
    testTable.extend(3);
    testTable(1) := 111;
    testTable(2) := 222;
    testTable(3) := 333;

    --query
    select *
    from users
    where id in testTable; <---------------- ERROR!
end;
```

The error is shown as:

> Error(427,31): PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

How to fix this?

Comment: No, nested table that is declared inside a PL/SQL block cannot be used in a query. To be able to reference a nested table inside a PL/SQL block, it needs to be declared at schema level. Moreover, a `select` statement inside a PL/SQL block has to have `into` clause(it needs to store returned values somewhere).

Comment: tks for the note about 'schema level'. about 'into' clause, i know it :), the above is just test code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option would be to define the collection in SQL rather than in PL/SQL.  Your procedure is doing a `SELECT` that isn't returning data into a local variable and that isn't being used to open a cursor-- that's not allowed whether you're using a collection or not.  In my example, I'll do a `COUNT(*)` into a local variable-- you might want to do something else.

```
-- Calling it StrTable when it's a table of numbers seems odd
CREATE TYPE StrTable 
    IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE PROCEDURE test
AS
  testTable StrTable;

  l_cnt     pls_integer;
BEGIN
  testTable := StrTable();

  --add values
  testTable.extend(3);
  testTable(1) := 111;
  testTable(2) := 222;
  testTable(3) := 333;

  -- query
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM users
   WHERE id IN (SELECT column_value
                  FROM TABLE( testTable ));

  dbms_output.put_line( l_cnt );
END;
```

And just to show that it works

```
SQL> exec test;
3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: i actually want a 'where .. in testTable', not 'from table(testTable)'

Comment: @JonDinham - That would just be `WHERE some_value IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE( testTable ))`.  If you want to edit your question to include a physical table and a more specific explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, I'd be happy to edit my answer.

Comment: i can make it now, i use "where id in (select * from table(testTable))". tks justin